# SQLite join with multiple matches

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables

```
PLAY
_id INTEGER
time INTEGER
```

```
SCORE
_id INTEGER
player_id INTEGER
play_id INTEGER
civilian INTEGER
scientific INTEGER
commercial INTEGER
military INTEGER
guilds INTEGER
treasury INTEGER
wonders INTEGER
progress INTEGER
total INTEGER
supremacy INTEGER
victory INTEGER
```

```
PLAYER
_id INTEGER
first_name INTEGER
last_name INTEGER
```

To every **PLAY** two **SCORE**'s are linked and to every **SCORE** one **PLAYER** is linked.

I want to `SELECT` every **PLAY** and the first name of the **PLAYER** of the first and second **SCORE** linked to each **PLAY**. I thought it would be possible using a `JOIN` statement but since I am no SQL expert I can't figure out how to do this. Is it even possible with the tables I have?

**EDIT:**
I tried the answer from Juan Carlos Oropeza with some modifications in the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT p._id, p.time, p1.first_name, p2.first_name
FROM play p
  JOIN score s1
    ON p._id = s1.play_id
  JOIN score s2
    ON p._id = s2.play_id
       AND s1.player_id <> s2.player_id
  JOIN player p1
    ON s1.player_id = p1._id
  JOIN player p2
    ON s2.player_id = p2._id
```

I got this result, the `_id` column contain **PLAY** id's

```
_id time            first_name  last_name
1   1504107269335   Jelmer      Amarinske
1   1504107269335   Amarinske   Jelmer
2   1504529628826   Jelmer      Amarinske
2   1504529628826   Amarinske   Jelmer
3   1504529644821   Jelmer      Amarinske
3   1504529644821   Amarinske   Jelmer
```

It's almost perfect. Now I want only one row per play.

**EDIT:**

I added the suggestion from Juan Carlos Oropeza. And now I have the expected result.

```
1   1504107269335   Jelmer  Amarinske
2   1504529628826   Jelmer  Amarinske
3   1504529644821   Jelmer  Amarinske
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result. That would be great for us to help you.

Comment: I think you should show some same data along with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join twice against the score table. Then join each score with player to get the name

```
 SELECT p._id, p.time, p1.first_name, p2.first_name
 FROM play p
 JOIN score s1
   ON p._id = s1.play_id
 JOIN score s2
   ON p._id = s2.play_id
  AND s1.player_id < s2.player_id
 JOIN player p1
   ON s1.player_id = p1._id
 JOIN player p2
   ON s2.player_id = p2._id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! you are awesome! I'm almost there. The result is that I get two rows for each play. The second row has the player names switched. I only want one row for each play. I can somewhat understand why two rows are returned, but it puzzles me why the names get switched the second time.

Comment: Change `<>`  to `s1.player_id < s2.player_id`

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. Can you explain why this worked?

Comment: At first you have two set, and you have `A <> B` and also `B <> A` that is why you have duplicated. Now `A > B` only happen once.

Comment: I think I understand. To verify, because `s1.player_id` is bigger than `s2.player_id` the second time the `JOIN` is performed the row is skipped?

Comment: You have the same set twice. At first I use `<>` because otherwise you will also get `A = A`. The `ON`  condition tell you what rows will be join, if the condition isn't meet then the join doesn't happen. With the `<>` the join was matching more than you want so we use a more restrict condition.

Comment: I changed `s1.player_id < s2.player_id` into `s1._id < s2._id`. This way the order in which the scores are inserted into the database is kept.